# Is there any Raspberry Pi images with GIT?

Tags: image, git

I am looking to see if GIT is part of the standard install / image for any of the Raspberry Pi images.  I am seeing many links for projects to use git or github or something, but I am not sure if its part of the standard image/install on the Raspberry Pi image.  I know I probably could download it, but it seems like its something that everyone is using for all these projects and definitely something that should be included.

**Is GIT part of the standard image on any Raspberry Pi distros?**

Comment: Why on earth does it matter?  Just install git if it isn't already present.  Even if it currently is or isn't present in a distribution does not mean that fact can't change in the future.

Comment: Many people use their RPi to watch movies, run a mail/web server or play retro games. Why would they want `git` included in their images?

Comment: as a simple response, more people use the RPi for applications and programs that are derived from a git repository than anything else.  Even the people who do use it as a mail/web server typically clone a git repo from somewhere.       
It only matters as a matter of convenience and what works the best with the system that is installed.  We have all installed third-party applications that get buggy and don't work 100% or are cumbersome.  Its also nice to have something that is utilized so much be included with the image and packages so as they update so will git and the tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's in Raspbian, I believe.

It's installed by default in Raspbian Jessie (desktop) but not Jessie Lite.
To install in Jessie lite, it's just `sudo apt install git-core`.

Comment: It's installed by default in Raspbian Jessie (desktop) but not Jessie Lite. To install in Jessie lite, it's just `sudo apt install git-core`.

Comment: Thank you ben_nuttall, that helps greatly.  Its nice to know that its the git core and the git core install and not a different extension.